# Word spacing is insufficient following an <em> element

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out how to make the correct amount of space after an italicised word. My italicised/emphasised word, in an `<em>` element, appears too close to the following word.

[image: Italicised word too close to next word]

I tried to add word-spacing with the `::after` pseudo-selector, but it has no effect and `content: " "` doesn’t do anything with actual placement of letters. Adding another space in the `<h3>` or `<em>` tag doesn’t work either. Is there a style such as `word-spacing-right` which can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve occurs when the true italic style of a font is not available to the browser, typically because the website author omitted to reference it. You have not posted any of your code, so I don’t know if this applies to your case, but it’s my guess that it does. If so, then the solution is simply to reference the true italic style of the font.

The two snippets below demonstrate the problem and the solution.

In this first snippet, the true italic style of the font is not referenced. The browser **simulates** italic type by simply slanting the letters of the normal type. However, the italicised word is not spaced correctly: the gap before it is too big, and the gap after it too small. Not by much, but enough to be noticeable.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amaranth:wght@700&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: Amaranth;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
Red <em>Red</em> Red
```

In this second snippet, the true italic style of the font is referenced (in addition to the normal style). Note that the italic letters are shaped differently; that’s because the true italic style has been carefully and thoughtfully crafted by the font designer. The designer also specifies the correct spacing between letters and between words, including the spacing between italic and normal type.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amaranth:ital,wght@0,700;1,700&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: Amaranth;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
Red <em>Red</em> Red
```

Here is an excerpt from the CSS `@font-face` rules imported from the Google link in the second snippet. You should ensure that your code contains something similar.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amaranth';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url(https://example.com/xyz.woff2) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amaranth';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url(https://example.com/xyz-italic.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another hack is to declare `word-spacing` for `span` and wrap it around the `em` and the following word.

```css
span {word-spacing: .25ch}
```

```html
You <span><em>know</em> you</span> want to
```

However, I think a better hack (when the actual italic font isn't being used) is to define `margin-right`

```css
em {margin-right: .25ch}
```

```css
p {
  font: bold xx-large sans-serif;
  line-height: .5em;
}

em {color: firebrick}


span {word-spacing: .25ch}

p:nth-child(3) em {margin-right: .25ch}
```

```html
<p>You <em>know</em> you want to</p>

<p>You <span><em>know</em> you</span> want to (span)</p>

<p>You <em>know</em> you want to (margin)</p>
```

Comment: I quite liked "margin-right" solution. I will remember that for the future use. Thanks

Comment: @Tim R and you can show more than one Example. Great.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a space between words after an  element in HTML, you can achieve that using CSS. You can use the ::after pseudo-element to add content after the  element and apply a margin-left property to create a space between the content and the text that follows the  element. Here's an example:

```html
<p>This is <em>emphasized</em> text. Following text.</p>

<style>
em::after {
  content: " "; /* Add a space after the <em> element */
  margin-left: 5px; /* Adjust the space size as needed */
}
</style>
```

Comment: I noticed that `content: " "` doesn't increase the spacing any more than `content: ""` does. I assume this is because the whitespace collapses. The only visual difference is when the text is highlighted. Additionally, the same effect can be created by adding the margin directly to `em` instead of its pseudo-element.

Comment: I confirmed my suspicion of the spaces collapsing by adding the declaration `white-space: pre`. The margin declaration is then unnecessary.